# Power BI Report Builder error: "The result set returned by the server is not a rowset"

Tags: report-builder2.0

I'm new to using paginated reports in Power BI, but have an existing query that runs successfully in Query Designer, but doesn't when I try to use it in Power BI Report Builder...

`EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('10) Invoice Detail (VBRP)'[Ordering Customer (Billing)], '10) Invoice Detail (VBRP)'[SAP ContractNo], '10) Invoice Detail (VBRP)'[Invoice No (Billing)], '10) Invoice Detail (VBRP)'[Invoice Type Description], '10) Invoice Detail (VBRP)'[Billing Date (Billing) (New)], '10) Invoice Detail (VBRP)'[Billing Qty (Billing)], '10) Invoice Detail (VBRP)'[Actual Invoiced Qty], '10) Invoice Detail (VBRP)'[VAT Amount (Billing)], '10) Invoice Detail (VBRP)'[Billing Item Net Value (Billing)], '10) Invoice Detail (VBRP)'[Material No (Billing)], '10) Invoice Detail (VBRP)'[Material Description (Billing)], FILTER(VALUES('10) Invoice Detail (VBRP)'[IsLastMonth]), ('10) Invoice Detail (VBRP)'[IsLastMonth] = "TRUE")))`

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWzau.png)

I've tried to increase the Time out to 100 seconds but it still didn't work - see screen-shot of error message (result set returned by the server is not a rowset).

Where am I going wrong and how can I resolve the issue?